# How do I make an infinite loop in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have written a C# program that should loop the code to refresh the DateTime info and set the text of a label to match.  However, when I run it, the form doesn't display.  Why does this happen, and how do I make the form be shown?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Clock
    {
        static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new clock());
            }
        }
    }
```

Ignoring my indentions (which may or may not be right, but are correct in the program), what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Logan Slowik

Comment: Best way to debug this is probably to put a break-point on the line `Application.Run(new clock())` and see if you even reach it

Comment: Your problem isn't in the provided code.

Comment: And in answer to the title question... while(true) { ... }

Comment: @DangerZone it is. it's just very badly indented!

Comment: @series0ne, so it is... Usually when programs are poorly indented, it is **much** more obvious...

Comment: Well, what's going on in the `clock` class?  We can't see it from here.

Comment: @DangerZone totally agree! (and I lol'd at that! :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are blocking the UI thread with your infinite loop. You can utilize `async` to avoid blocking your UI... Just call this method in your Form_Load method. `InfiniteLoop();`

```
async void InfiniteLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        this.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

You may also consider using `Timer`